# Jenkins: Build error

Tags: jenkins

I recently encountered this build error in Jenkins:

```
Started by upstream project "sampapp-web-qa-build" build number 1445
originally caused by:
Started by user John Santiago
Started by upstream project "sampapp-web-qa-build" build number 1445
originally caused by:
Started by user John Santiago
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sampapp-web-qa-update-db
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@git.sampapp.com:sampapp/sampapp.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@git.sampapp.com:sampapp/sampapp.git
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress git@git.samapp.com:sampapp/sampapp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/testing^{commit}" # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/testing^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 3a23984ab747c25102bf5a2cbda83288565cd75a (refs/remotes/origin/testing)
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 3a23984ab747c25102bf5a2cbda83288565cd75a
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list 3a23984ab747c25102bf5a2cbda83288565cd75a # timeout=10
[sampapp-web-qa-update-db] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\Jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson8340343356667040511.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sampapp-web-qa-update-db>cd sampapp-web   && npm install 
npm WARN package.json MyFinancialsOnline@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json MyFinancialsOnline@1.0.0 No README data
[sampapp-web-qa-update-db] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\Jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson7963468173587450282.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\sampapp-web-qa-update-db>cd sampapp-web   && grunt update_db 
[4mRunning "liquibase:update_mfp" (liquibase) task[24m
INFO 8/6/17 6:47 AM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 8/6/17 6:47 AM: liquibase: Reading from [dbo].[DATABASECHANGELOG]
INFO 8/6/17 6:47 AM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Validation Failed:
    1 change sets check sum
        ../samp-db/scripts/2017_06/changelog.xml::20170619_TCompany_Add_CabinetPath1::a.smith is now: 7:f4bbb21c04dcd157e94b19835b6ba71d


SEVERE 8/6/17 6:47 AM: liquibase: Validation Failed:
    1 change sets check sum
        ../samp-db/scripts/2017_06/changelog.xml::20170619_TCompany_Add_CabinetPath1::a.smith is now: 7:f4bbb21c04dcd157e94b19835b6ba71d

liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
    1 change sets check sum
        ../samp-db/scripts/2017_06/changelog.xml::20170619_TCompany_Add_CabinetPath1::a.smith is now: 7:f4bbb21c04dcd157e94b19835b6ba71d

at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:196)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:196)
at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1032)
at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:177)
at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:96)


For more information, use the --logLevel flag
[33mWarning: spawn OK  Use --force to continue.[39m

[31mAborted due to warnings.[39m
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
Finished: FAILURE
```

- I see timeout in the error messages, could this be a timeout error?
- I also see a validation failed message, could this be the cause of
  the build error?

Could Git be the problem or have my files been corrupted somehow due to the validation error?

Comment: Just a generic advise: Manually perform the steps that `grunt update_db` does. By gut instinct I'd say this is a liquibase issue not able to perform the requested operation. There is no timeout issue - this is just a reminder that the operation before the comment is subject to a (default) timeout of 10 minutes.